# Probability with Expected values

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, expected-value

Question:
Jill goes for a day of rock climbing. She rents a wall for $50$ Dollars, and the agent asks if she wants to add insurance for an extra $10$ dollars. Insurance would cover the cost of damage in case the wall breaks or damages; otherwise fee is $150$ Dollars. She estimates that the chance she will damage the wall is $3\%$. Should she buy the insurance?

I started the question by trying to identify the costs given each scenario.

|  | Buy Insurance | Don't buy Insurance |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Wall doesn't break | 60 Dollars | 50 Dollars |
| Wall does break | 60 Dollars | 200 Dollars |

After this point, I tried to find the expected value of wall breaking.

$$E(break) = (.97)(60)+(.03)(500) = 73.2$$

Would I compare this number the expected value of the wall not breaking to see if she would buy the insurance or do I need to look at another value?

Comment: I have the following table values for the column "Don't buy Insurance": $\$ 50$ (no break) and $\$ 200$ (break). Are the values comprehensible?

Comment: @callculus42 Yeah, that's my mistake, but you're right, it should be what you got.

Comment: It pleases me, that the comment has helped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Guide:

Glad that you attempted the question.

- First, check the entry of your table. If the wall doesn't break and you do not purchase the insurance, the cost is not that high. Please edit your table.
- You should analyze what is the decision that you get to make. Your decision variable here is to purchase the insurance or not. We do not compute the expected value of whether the wall breaks or not.
- Assuming that you make decision based on comparing the expected value of each decision and then pick the expected lower cost. Then you should compute the expected cost for purchasing insurance or not.

E(buy insurance) is $60$.

After you correct your table, compute the expected value from not buying the insurance and pick the smaller expected cost.

Do give a further attempt.

Follow up: Please read up on utility function as well to understand the human decision making process better.